# Remove Max and Min values from python list of integers

Tags: python, list, max, min

I am not completely green to Python, but I am interested in learning/keeping good practices while I develop my skills.

I want to remove the high and low values from a list of numbers, which I know how to do, but am curious if there is a better/preferred way to do this.

```
mylist = [1, 4, 0, 3, 2]
mylist.sort() #[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
trimmed = mylist[1:-1] #[1, 2, 3]
```

I get the desired answer, but did I get the right answer appropriately?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here's another way to do it if you don't want to change the order of the items:

```
mylist = [1, 4, 0, 3, 2]
mylist.remove(max(mylist))
mylist.remove(min(mylist))
```

Assumes that the high/low don't have any duplicates in the list, or if there are, that it's OK to remove only one of them.

This will need to do 2-4 passes through the list: two to find the max and min values, and up to 2 to find the values to remove (if they both happen to be at the end of the list). You could reduce this to one by writing a Python loop to find the max and min in a single pass (and remember the index of each so you can delete the items by index after the loop). However, `min()` and `max()` are implemented in C, so replacing them with Python code would probably result in lower performance even if it allowed you to reduce the number of passes.

Comment: Note that doing 4 passes is still probably faster than sorting the list, but if you want `mylist` to remain and have the trimmed version in `trimmed`, you should copy it first.

Comment: Yep. `trimmed = mylist[:]` and then do the manipulations on `trimmed`.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this because I had duplicates in the list I was trying to modify, so instead of running mylist.remove(min(mylist)) multiple times because it only removes one value at a time I modified it in one line

```
mylist = [i for i in mylist if i > min(mylist) and i < max(mylist)]
```

Comment: This evaluates `min(my_list)` and `max(myList)` once for every item in the list!

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove max element and store the list in a variable and same with min element. By using remove function if I stored it in variable it gives none as
output. So to store it

```py
arr = [1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
arr.sort()
remmax = arr[0:-1]
remmin = arr[1:]
print(remmax)
print(remmin)
```