# How to delete the min value of array an print the size in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Following code gets a value as the first input(a) e.g 7 and then get 7 separate values as 2nd input(b). I want to delete the min value of second input each time and the print the size of renaming input(b). For example if b = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6]) the output should be 7 6 4 3. The code raised with error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(int(input('Enter a value'))) 
b = [ ] 
 
for i in range(a):
    elem =  np.array(int(input('Enter values :')))
    b.append ( elem )
unique = np.unique(b)
num_unique=len(unique)
num_unique=num_unique-1
for i in range(num_unique):
    b =(b[b > min(b)])
    print(np.size(b))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Max and Min values from python list of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656670/remove-max-and-min-values-from-python-list-of-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b > min(b)` creates a boolean array. `b` is a list and cannot be indexed by boolean array. A `np.array`, though, can be indexed by boolean array.

Just need to insert `b = np.array(b)` right after constructing `b`

```py
a = int(input('Enter a value'))
b = [ ] 
 
for i in range(a):
    elem = int(input('Enter values :'))   # no need to convert scaler to array here 
    b.append ( elem )

b = np.array(b)        # <-----
unique = np.unique(b)
num_unique = len(unique)
num_unique = num_unique - 1
for i in range(num_unique):
    b = b[b > min(b)]
    print(np.size(b))
```

Comment: Thanks, if I insert it after b=[] it will raise with erroe "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'", where should I insert it in my code?

Comment: @user14263018 updated. It is a common pattern to (finish) constructing a list and then convert it to a numpy array